# network unclaimed for ar9565 qualcom Atheros

Tags: wireless, drivers

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0600000-c067ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb0ffff

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
 lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia

lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network     Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8800M Series]

lsmod:
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             32867  0 
ppdev                  17114  0 
rfcomm                 47562  12 
bnep                   18240  2 
joydev                 17694  0 
btusb                  22432  0 
coretemp               13642  0 
kvm_intel             137888  0 
kvm                   422160  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
aesni_intel            51134  0 
cryptd                 20531  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    46366  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36726  1 
dell_wmi               12682  0 
sparse_keymap          13891  1 dell_wmi
snd_hda_intel          43682  5 
snd_hda_codec         188269  3     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm                97523  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
psmouse               102541  0 
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
wmi                    19257  1 dell_wmi
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
dell_laptop            17426  0 
dcdbas                 14491  1 dell_laptop
snd                    83674  20     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_rawmidi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mac_hid                13254  0 
fglrx                6728782  137 
dm_multipath           23306  0 
scsi_dh                14589  1 dm_multipath
uvcvideo               78117  0 
videobuf2_core         33025  1 uvcvideo
i915                  600141  2 
videodev              125126  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
ath3k                  12918  0 
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
rts5139               350620  0 
bluetooth             212001  25 rfcomm,bnep,btusb,ath3k
soundcore              15092  1 snd
microcode              23030  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
amd_iommu_v2           19228  1 fglrx
snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
drm_kms_helper         49259  1 i915
drm                   290595  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13565  1 i915
video                  19653  1 i915
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
dm_raid45              78156  0 
xor                    17153  1 dm_raid45
dm_mirror              22204  0 
dm_region_hash         20962  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18565  3 dm_raid45,dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
r8169                  62741  0 
btrfs                 781180  0 
ahci                   25869  2 
libahci                27338  1 ahci
zlib_deflate           27140  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12645  1 btrfs

uname -a:
Linux mypc 3.5.0-44-generic #67~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 16:16:57 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried lot of links But nothing seem to be working...

Comment: Run these in terminal and add them to your question:
  `sudo rfkill list all` 
  `lsusb`
  `lspci`
  `lsmod`
  `uname -a`

Comment: Done with the changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run this terminal command:

```
lspci -nn
```

I assume your wireless device is 168c:0036. Updated wireless drivers are required to claim this device. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic 
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Your wireless should be working.

If you have installed another competing driver package, I recomment you remove it. First, find it's exact name:

```
dpkg --list | grep ath9k
```

Then remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge oem-whatever-you-found
```

Confirm that the ath9k driver drives your device:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

It ought to show a driver, ath9k, and a wireless interface, ideally, wlan0.

Comment: still not working it says ->linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic is already the newest version.

Comment: Please try: linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic

Comment: :it installed properly but was no luck with wifi.on the other hand the system reported a crash report regarding oem -wirelesss-at9k-dkms driver when i tried to send it it gave me an error that it was not official unbuntu package.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: i removed the oem driver and again followed the steps but hadn't any luck with it.so i did sme research on the forum and came across:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044 it worked.thanks for your time.